# jquery validate single key callback

Tags: jquery, callback, validation

I'm using jquery validate to validate my forms. I want to show a text field that is hidden when my This field is valid.

That is i want call a method when a text field is valid(on text field change, before clicking submit).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the validate plugin but hopefully it should slot in fairly easily here.

Attach a keyup event to your text field.  The function you call should assess if the field is valid and show/hide the hidden text box accordingly.

```
$("theTextboxID").keyup(function() {
    var isValid = $(this).validate() //or whatever you need to validate
    if (isValid) {
        // I show by removing display:none
        $("hiddenTextBoxID").removeAttr("style");
    }
    else {
        // I hide by adding style=display:none
        $("hiddenTextBoxID").attr("style", "display:none");
    }
});
```